# Exporting interactive jupyter/ipython3 session to Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I like to work on the `jupyter` console on the terminal very much. I am interested in exporting my history to a Jupyter notebook (`*.ipynb`) file to share with colleagues. How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in magic command `%notebook` is used for this even in the console/qtconsole clients.

```
%notebook /tmp/foo.ipynb
```

You may need to add `-e` or `--export` on older versions but check the docstring on your version with `%notebook?`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @gdahlm. I checked, and in IPython 6.1.0 the `-e` or `--export` flag is deprecated. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.